# Get SVG-Object_s at given coordinates?

Tags: svg, coordinates

I'd like to obtain object IDs from an SVG-file via coordinates.

For example in

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
   height="50" width="50">
   <rect id="rectRED"
 x="15" y="5" height="30" width="30"
        style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:0.5;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.5" />
   <rect id="rectBLUE"
 x="5" y="15" height="30" width="30"
        style="fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:0.5;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.5" />
</svg>
```

- `getObjectsAt(10,25)` should return a List containing `rectBLUE`
- `getObjectsAt(25,25)` should return a List containing `rectRED` and `rectBLUE`
- `getObjectsAt(10,10)` should return something like `NIL`

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more information if you want an answer. Which programming language are you working in? Are you using any libraries?

Comment: It is mainly this single task - so language doesn't really matter - quick and dirty scripting would be fine.
PHP would be very nice, because the SVGs are generated via PHP - but even that is not optimal, I guess a language capable of solving the getObjectsAt-Task would do that better, too ;)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint

Comment: To add a little detail: I generate aperiodic patterns (i.e. Penroses) - large SVGs tiled by manny polygons. Now I whant to try to build a cellular automaton (like Conways GOL) on thoose aperiodic grids. The Problem is getting the colors of neighbourcells - whitch i hope to optain via something like getObjectAt(x,y).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) method, but it only returns the topmost element. To get all the elements under a point you could find the topmost one, hide it and look at the point again until no more elements are there:

```
var elementsAt = function( x, y ){
    var elements = [], current = document.elementFromPoint( x, y );
    // at least one element was found and it's inside a ViewportElement
    // otherwise it would traverse up to the <html> root of jsfiddle webiste.
    while( current &&  current.nearestViewportElement ){
        elements.push( current );
        // hide the element and look again
        current.style.display = "none";
        current = document.elementFromPoint( x, y );
    }
    // restore the display
    elements.forEach( function( elm ){
       elm.style.display = ''; 
    });
    return elements;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duo02d38/